# Can I play night or community operations in PS3?

Tags: ps3, battlefield-4

So I heard that Battlefield 4 has free maps for Playstation 3.
I went to the store, and there really was Night Operations and Community Operations, freely downloadable.

Installed it, but the problem is that in the game, I cannot play on the designated maps. On the default playlist I can only "Buy DLC", and when I filter the maps with server browser, same thing happens: "Buy DLC".

So, is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to go to the buy DLC option, download it (the night operations and community operations DLCs are free) and then quit the game, where you go to select 'battlefield 4' with the blue disk icon is where you are going to go to install the downloaded DLC.   Select to start Night Operations or Community Operations like you were going to play them as a game.   An installer will pop up and run.   After it is finished you will be able to play that DLC's game mode like any other.